# Pinning Media Center to Windows 7 Taskbar causes Explorer to crash

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash, windows-media-center

When I right-click the Windows Media Center icon and choose "Pin to Taskbar", Explorer crashes.  Anyone else experiencing this?

**Edit:**  Here's the info from the error posted to the event log:

> Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 6.1.7600.16404, time stamp: 0x4a765076  Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdadb
>   Exception code: 0xc0000374
>   Fault offset: 0x000c283b
>   Faulting process id: 0x810
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01ca5ce5c4357b90
>   Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
>   Report Id: a9826acc-c9a7-11de-ae58-0019dbb59136

Comment: I get this exact error, although when right-clicking on various things (desktop, Recycle Bin, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It works on my machine - Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

You could try running diagnostic tests on the RAM using the Memory tester that comes with Windows - it might be a memory problem.  You can get to this by booting from the Windows DVD and the Repair option.

Comment: Hi Anthony, and welcome to SuperUser. SuperUser is unlike most other website, as it is not intended for discussion. Your response would have been better suited for a comment on the original question as what you wrote does not actually *solve* C-Pound Guru's problem.

Comment: Thanks josh - I have added some more information to my answer